# How to delete an inherited private char* attribute? (example : in a destructor)

Tags: c++, inheritance, attributes, char

I am trying to delete the inherited `char*` attribute in this program :

In A.h

```
class A {    
  public :
    // Functions, constructors and such
  private :
    char* attribute;
}
```

In B.h

```
#include "A.h"

class B : public A {
  public :
    B(const char* _attribute, int s) : A(_attribute) {setSpeed(s);}
    ~B()
  private :
    int speed;
}
```

With delete [] in a destructor like so :

```
B::~B() {
  delete [] attribute;
}
```

But I get this error : `char*A::attribute' is private

In A's destuctor (`~A()`) I use the same "destroy [] attribute" and it works...

Comment: Because I create the object from B with the inherited attribute from A, and to destroy it I use the destructor from B since there are additionnal attributes in B.

Comment: See that `A(_attribute)` handing off that `char *` to A? That should tell you something about who's destructor should be responsible for destroy said-same. I'm surmising it isn't private to A just for no reason in particular. There is probably reason behind it. So let ~A() take care of it. It will be called  once ~B() is finished up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is private to A, A should be the class that takes the responsibility of deleting it.

You shouldn't delete it in B, that violates basic encapsulation. B should only take care of deleting its own attributes.

Comment: Then how should I actually call A's destructor from B?

Comment: @user1944839, `A`'s destructor will automatically be called after `B`'s. Anyway, consider using a `std::string` instead of a `char *`. Then, no one has to clean up after it.

Comment: @user1944839 No. When a destructor of a class finishes execution, it automatically calls the destructor of the base class (all of them if multiple inheritance is involved).

Comment: Sorry, I am asking because I am obligated to use a char*.

Comment: Oooooh! Well that's useful information. Thank you a ton for helping me people! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute in class A is defined as private, so it is not inherited by class B. It does not exist in class B. That's why you can not delete it.

Try using protected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a base class's private variable from a derived class. You need to make it protected if you want it to be accessed from derived classes.